# Given the family of solutions find the diff. eq.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Given the following 2-parameter family of solutions, find the differential equation which is satisfied by them.

The family of solutions is: $$\log(y)=c_{1}x^{2}+c_{2}$$

and the resulting differential equation should be:

$$xyy''-yy'-x(y')^2=0$$

How do I get to the differential equation given the family of solutions?

Comment: @Mattos can you help with it besides editing the text? ;)

Comment: Just differentiate both sides with respect to $x$ to compute $y', y''$, then show that the multiplication of these functions in a particular order $= 0$.

Comment: Just leave it up in case someone else wants to know how to approach this kind of problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your goal is to get rid of the constants.
So
$$
\eqalign{
  & \ln y = c_{\,1} x^{\,2}  + c_{\,2}   \cr 
  & y = e^{c_{\,1} x^{\,2}  + c_{\,2} }  = a_{\,2} \,e^{c_{\,1} x^{\,2} }   \cr 
  & y' = 2c_{\,1} x\,a_{\,2} \,e^{c_{\,1} x^{\,2} }  = 2c_{\,1} x\,y  \cr 
  & y'' = 2c_{\,1} \,a_{\,2} \,e^{c_{\,1} x^{\,2} }  + 4c_{\,1} ^2 x\,a_{\,2} \,e^{c_{\,1} x^{\,2} }  = 2c_{\,1} \,y + 2c_{\,1} x\,y'  \cr 
  & xyy'' = \left( {2c_{\,1} x\,y} \right)\,y + \left( {2c_{\,1} x\,y} \right)\,x\,y'  \cr 
  & xyy'' - yy'\, - x\,\left( {y'} \right)^2  = 0 \cr} 
$$

Of course, since we have multiplied by $xy$ we must then add appropriate conditions
to deal for the cases $x=0$ and $y=0$

Answer (score 0):

With advice from Mattos I found the way myself:
$$\frac{d}{dx}log(y)=\frac{d}{dx}c_1x^{2}+c_2$$
$$\frac{y'}{yln(10)}=2c_1x$$
$$y'=2c_1ln(10)xy$$
$$y''=2c_1ln(10)\frac{d}{dx}xy=2c_1ln(10)(y+xy')=\frac{y'}{x}+\frac{(y')^2}{y}$$
From that the answer follows: $$xyy''-yy'-x(y')^2=0$$